# Cocoa: Local Declaration of 'amountOfReservations' hides instance variable. What's wrong?

Tags: cocoa, variables, instance, local, declaration

```
-(id)init{
    int amountOfReservations = 0;
    NSNumber *amountOfReservationsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:amountOfReservations];
    [reservationsAmount addObject:amountOfReservationsNumber];
    return self;
}
```

The Issue navigator says: 
*NSNumber *amountOfReservationsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:**amountOfReservations**];*

**Local Declaration of 'amountOfReservations' hides instance variable**

What is wrong? Help me please...

Answer (score 2):

Your class has an instance variable called `amountOfReservations`. You better rename the name the variable in your `init` method to e.g. `localAmountOfReservations`.

By the way, you need to call `[super init];` in your `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens if you declared the variable in your header file

```
int amountOfReservationsNumber
```

and when you want to use it in your init you declare it *again*. You are "locally" (as in inside a method) declaring a variable that was already declared "globally" as being an int in the .h file.